# Is there any IEEE 754 standard implementations for Java floating point primitives?

Tags: java, floating-point, double, bigdecimal, ieee-754

I'm interested if Java is using IEEE 754 standard for implementing its floating point arithmetic. [Here](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) I saw this kind of thing in documentation:

> operation defined in IEEE 754-2008

As I understand positive side of IEEE 754 is to increase precision of floating point arithmetics so if I'll use `double` or `float` in Java would presision of computations be same as in `BigDecimal`? And if not than what's the point of using IEEE 754 standard in [`Math`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) class?

Comment: Links are broken.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> I'm interested if Java is using IEEE 754 standard for implementing it's floating point arithmetic.

IEEE-754 defines standards for *multiple* floating-point types. For many years, they were all *binary* floating point; that's what Java's `float` and `double` are: `float` is a 32-bit IEEE-754 binary floating point value (what the standard calls [`binary32`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format)). `double` is a 64-bit one (what the standard calls [`binary64`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)). These binary floating point numbers are very efficient for computers to calculate, but because they work in binary and we work in decimal, there are some expectation mismatches; for instance, `0.1` cannot be stored precisely in a `double`, and you get oddities like `0.1 + 0.2` turning out to be `0.30000000000000004`. See [*Is floating point math broken?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) for details. They're not a good choice for financial calculations, for instance.

`BigDecimal` is a Java class that implements *decimal* fractional numbers with arbitrary precision. It's much slower than using `double`, but the results fit with our decimal-minded expectations (for instance, that `0.1 + 0.2` will be `0.3`).

The 2008 edition of IEEE-754 adds significant new formats, in particular [`decimal32`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal32_floating-point_format), [`decimal64`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal64_floating-point_format), and [`decimal128`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal128_floating-point_format). These are *decimal* floating point, and so they work the same way that we do. `0.1` can be accurately stored in a `decimal64`. `0.1 + 0.2` is `0.3` in `decimal64`. However, as far as I can tell, they aren't really relevant to your question.

Since `BigDecimal` predates IEEE-754 2008 (by some margin), it defines its own semantics.

> And if not than what's the point of using IEEE 754 standard in Math class?

JDK9 adds new operations to `Math` that do things defined by the IEEE-754 2008 spec (such as [`fma`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#fma-float-float-float-), which does a [fused multiply-add](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiply%E2%80%93accumulate_operation#Fused_multiply.E2.80.93add)), and so it defines those operations with reference to the IEEE-754 2008 spec, for clarity.

More reading:

- [IEEE-754 on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point)
- [`BigDecimal` JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)

Comment: Does the semantics of `BigDecimal` differ from `decimalxx` when a precision is specified? E.g., does `new BigDecimal("0.1",  MathContext.DECIMAL64)` differ from `decimal64`?

Comment: @Safron - I've never gone deep into the semantics of either of them, but yes, I *suspect* so given that `BigDecimal` defines an immutable object type with methods, and the IEEE-754 `decimalXX` types are primitives. They may well have different default rounding behaviors, etc., esp. as `BigDecimal`'s are configurable per instance.

Comment: @TJCrowder I suspected something like that, but it seems we were both wrong. :) From the documentation of `DECIMAL64`: *A MathContext object with a precision setting matching the precision of the IEEE 754-2019 decimal64 format, 16 digits, and a rounding mode of HALF_EVEN.* (see https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/math/MathContext.html#DECIMAL64)

Comment: @Safron - That's just precision, not semantics. :-)

Comment: @TJCrowder You're right, it seems I was a bit too fast. I found the actual semantic differences in the documentation of Java 17. See section "Relation to IEEE 754 Decimal Arithmetic" in https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html